# why would ABSPATH not get defined

Tags: errors, constants

Last week I got an error in my logs on a standard WP install -

```
Use of undefined constant ABSPATH - assumed 'ABSPATH' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /wp-settings.php on line 33
```

I have ABSPATH defined in wp-config as standard:

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
```

And it seems the site only accessed wp-settings because of the next line in wp-config:

```
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

Yet when it went to wp-settings, ABSPATH was not defined?

There is only one error like this, and the site works fine.  What could be causing ABSPATH not to be defined, to throw this once off error?

Comment: Can you see the request it was attached to? I'd guess the user went to /wp-settings.php directly rather than a normal request to the site.

Comment: It just showed in the error log. So you think it may have been some spider or hack creating the error?  I went to site/wp-settings.php and got 500 error & produced in the error log!  Seems like a good explanation, I thought there may be some site error.  Is there a way to stop this error?  Exit/die function or somthing?

Comment: Most of the core files do already have an `if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) )` guard at the top to test if they've been loaded separately, but there are a handful that don't. You could probably configure your webserver to reject requests for wp-settings, and I'd guess there are some Apache configurations already out there set up for this and lots of other small tweaks like that, but I've never run one myself.

Comment: its nginx but Ill look into it thanks